# I am trying to create multiple table user and admin login in laravel, getting error

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I made changes in auth file but still, I am getting an error.

> Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must
>   be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given,
>   called in
>   C:\LMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php on
>   line 123

```
return [
         'defaults' => [
                       'guard' => 'web',
                       'passwords' => 'users',
                       ],

           'admin1' => [
                         'driver' => 'eloquent',
                        'model' => App\RegisterOperation::class,
                       ],

    'guards' => [

        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

         'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
 'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin1',
        ],




          'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

    ],
       'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],


],




    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: By using role in users table you can do this in easy way.

Comment: Thank you @Kirit, But I have 4 different types of user like admin, employee, student, and evaluator, and they have different fields may be 10 t 25 columns. it can't not one table.

Comment: You can use users table as you can add more fields or you can create new tables for different roles and give reference to the users table.

Comment: but again reference column contains, a different table and according to the role I need to fetch.

Comment: for common field use users table like, name, email, password, etc.. for other fields use separate table and give reference of the users table. like for student use id, user_id, roll_no, enroll_no, etc.
Please refere this link may it will help you: https://www.kerneldev.com/2018/02/12/set-up-role-based-access-control-in-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

correct your guard, you have something missing under your providers

```
return [
         'defaults' => [
                       'guard' => 'web',
                       'passwords' => 'users',
                       ],



    'guards' => [

        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

         'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
 'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin1',
        ],




          'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

    ],
       'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
'admin1' => [
                         'driver' => 'eloquent',
                        'model' => App\RegisterOperation::class,
                       ],

],




    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: but am not sure the major problem is from here, show your LoginController and your Route

Answer (score 0):

Use this package It you give the best support for multiple role based user 
https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust